# undefined reference to `URLDownloadToFileA@20'

Tags: c, windows, http, mingw, download

Я пытаюсь скачать файл с некоего сайта, сам файл там есть, но дело в другом. Почему-то при попытке скомпилировать файл с кодом вылетает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5iMw9H.o:download.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `URLDownloadToFileA@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Почему это происходит? Вот мой код (весь код в программе):

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<urlmon.h>
int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    LPCTSTR Url = "http://cplusplus.com/img/cpp-logo.png";
    LPCTSTR File = "D:\\Desktop\\cpp-logo.png";
    hr = URLDownloadToFileA(0, Url, File, 0, 0);
}
```

По-моему, там надо какой-то параметр командной строки ввести, а какой -- не помню.

--- РЕШЕНИЕ ---

Лазить по польским форумам у меня в планах не было, но я нашел решение: да, дело было в ключе командной строки, нужно просто добавить "-lurlmon" и всё заработает!

Comment: просто добавьте в перед main такое `#pragma comment(lib, "Urlmon")` либо добавьте линковщику Urlmon.lib

Comment: @KoVadim Всё такая же ошибка

Comment: я не увидел, что там mingw, pragma comment работает только для студийного компилятора.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: а это тут при чем?